# Private distribution of Android App in the PlayStore

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have an Android app that I want to push to be available to download for users in our company.

But I don't want the app to be visible *publically* to all.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you should use invites. Upload in beta and invite your company members to try it. I think that should be the way. Let me know if there is other good option available.

Comment: @PragneshGhodaシ Hi Pragnesh, is there any other method that you know of? There will be over well 100 users that I would need to administrate via email invite

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Google G-Suite,

> You can use the managed Google Play store to host Android apps
>   specifically for your organization. You can control who can download
>   an app. You can also benefit from security checks, such as user
>   authentication and malware detection. You publish private apps to the
>   Play store from the Google Admin console or the Google Play Console.

Go through this link and follow the steps : 
[Manage Google Play private apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)

It has some FAQs. Please read this and check if it fulfills your requirements.